# CorruptedFrameException: on multiple addV() gremlin query in remote client

Tags: gremlin

Tool Set:
**DB Server**: TinkerPop/TinkerGraph  v 3.3.3 (Stanalone - using a conf/gremlin-server.yaml) (**channelizer**: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WsAndHttpChannelizer)

**Client** : Gremlin client from Java.

**Issue**: When I call the client.submitAsync() multiple times I receive an Exception.
The repeat count until exception is thrown differs if I change the query content. This indicates to me that it has something to be done at the client side configuration!

*2018-11-07 09:57:59.418 ERROR 20672 --- [n-driver-loop-2] o.a.t.g.d.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler : Could not process the response
io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded.
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.protocolViolation(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:412) ~[netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.decode(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:277) ~[netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489) ~[netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428) ~[netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) ~[netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) [netty-all-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increase the `connectionPool.maxContentLength` on the driver and `maxContentLength` in Gremlin Server beyond 65536. Ideally the two sizes should match on client and server, but I suppose it doesn't have to.

I assume you are submitting a very large script to the server based on this question. Take care with that. Large scripts, especially those that are not [parameterized](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#parameterized-scripts), can cause different problems to manifest in the behavior of your application.

Comment: Thankyou @stephen-mallette

Comment: To configure the Java driver properly, use `Cluster.build().maxContentLength(1048576).create()`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not on the addV() but one a seacrh to return all the Vertices. Before every add I did a search to fetch the lot of Vertices - to apply some logic. SO as every addV() increased the no of vertices, after a certain time the search (g.V()...) had the response content increasing. 
Time being this question can be considered as Answered. But I am in search to find on how to set the response content unbound about SIZE. While, I guess this is not what is suggested.